# FlipView in ListView DataTemplate Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-phone-8.1, flipview

I have a problem with a FlipView placed in a DataTemplate of a ListView: the FlipView doesn't scroll. If I place the FlipView outside of the DataTemplate it works properly.
I tried to set the ManipulationMode of the ListView as TranslateY and that of FlipView as translateX, but nothing changes. What can be the problem?

This is the FlipView code:

```
<FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource FlipTemplate}">
    <FlipView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemsPanel>
</FlipView>
```

Thank you!

**EDIT**

```
<ListView x:Name="lstPaths"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Routes}" 
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource RouteTemplate}">
     <ListView.FooterTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <Border Height="12" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.FooterTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**EDIT 2**

It seems that the ListView handles all manipulation events, which do not reach the FlipVew!

Comment: Post your XAML code for the LIstView as well.

Comment: Use ItemsControl instead of ListView check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30432368/1110871