# flipviews inside Dynamic listview not swipable

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, windows-store-apps, flipview

I have a listview that is populated during runtime from a webservice. Inside the data template of the listview I have made flipview, each flipview gets three images that user can swipe. I have attached an image of what i am looking for.

[image]

**ISSUE**

The flipview doesnt get user interactions. here is the xaml below

```
<ListView   ManipulationMode="None" IsZoomedInView="False"  IsSwipeEnabled="False" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding image}" ManipulationMode="All">
                    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding image}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                </FlipView>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: solved it by adding gridview instead of flipview.. then copying template of a flipview in blend and changing its target type to gridview and all other flipview tags inside the template to gridview... then binding style of the gridview to this template

Answer (score 1):

you have to apply a workaround here.

- use gridview instead of flipview.
- edit the template of the gridview(remove it and add (copy/paste) a flipview template instead)

next, **the trick**,

- change the target type of pasted tempate to gridview
- find/replace all other flipview tags inside the template with
  gridview tags
- last step,bind this new template to the gridview    (inside that
  listview)

Answer (score 0):

You can Add **ItemsControl** instead of ListView as ListView has some problems with inner controls that use horizontal gestures.

```
<ItemsControl>
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate >
    <DataTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <FlipView ItemsSource="{Binding image}" ManipulationMode="All">
                <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding image}" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            </FlipView>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

You may need to add ScrollViewer manually as ItemsControl doesn't have one